# How I can set expiration date for AsyncStorage - react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am using react native async storage it works good but in some cases, I have to set an expiration date for data and refresh my storage I checked

[AsyncStorage documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) but there are no options to set expire after a specific time.

only available options are:-

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first, I am storing objects, not strings so my solution will be based on object case if anyone uses strings he can append expireAt the object key then he will extract expire date and compare it with the current date

my solution:-

```
/**
 *
 * @param urlAsKey
 * @param expireInMinutes
 * @returns {Promise.<*>}
 */
async getCachedUrlContent(urlAsKey, expireInMinutes = 60) {

    let data = null;

    await AsyncStorage.getItem(urlAsKey, async (err, value) => {

        data = (JSON.parse(value));

        // there is data in cache && cache is expired
        if (data !== null && data['expireAt'] &&
            new Date(data.expireAt) < (new Date())) {

            //clear cache
            AsyncStorage.removeItem(urlAsKey);


            //update res to be null
            data = null;
        } else {

            console.log('read data from cache  ');

        }
    });

    //update cache + set expire at date
    if (data === null) {
        console.log('cache new Date ');

        //fetch data
        data = fetch(urlAsKey).then((response) => response.json())
            .then(apiRes => {

                //set expire at
                apiRes.expireAt = this.getExpireDate(expireInMinutes);

                //stringify object
                const objectToStore = JSON.stringify(apiRes);

                //store object
                AsyncStorage.setItem(urlAsKey, objectToStore);


                console.log(apiRes.expireAt);
                return apiRes;
            });

    }

    return data;


},

/**
 *
 * @param expireInMinutes
 * @returns {Date}
 */
getExpireDate(expireInMinutes) {
    const now = new Date();
    let expireTime = new Date(now);
    expireTime.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + expireInMinutes);
    return expireTime;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

AsyncStorage really only handles storage and nothing beyond that.

If you want to set an expiration, just put a key in your data for access date and set it to `new Date()`. Then, when you pull data, do a date check on the expiration key based on when it should expire.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this also, improvement from Ahmed Farag Mostafa answers

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default class ExpireStorage {
  static async getItem(key) {
    let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if (
      data !== null &&
      data.expireAt &&
      new Date(data.expireAt) < new Date()
    ) {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
      data = null;
    }
    return data?.value;
  }

  static async setItem(key, value, expireInMinutes) {
    const data = { value };
    if (expireInMinutes) {
      const expireAt = this.getExpireDate(expireInMinutes);
      data.expireAt = expireAt;
    } else {
      const expireAt = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(key))?.expireAt;
      if (expireAt) {
        data.expireAt = expireAt;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
    const objectToStore = JSON.stringify(data);
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, objectToStore);
  }

  static async removeItem(key) {
    return AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  static getExpireDate(expireInMinutes) {
    const now = new Date();
    const expireTime = new Date(now);
    expireTime.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + expireInMinutes);
    return expireTime;
  }
}
```