# deleting asyncstorage after a month in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

i am not sure if this is possible though. I am trying to store and delete an object data with AsyncStorage in react native and should only be deleted after a month. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537122/how-i-can-set-expiration-date-for-asyncstorage-react-native

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated by others, there is no built-in feature like yours. But what you can do as a workaround is saving the current date along with your data and check them periodically or whenever you use them and delete the expired ones. It is neither a direct nor the most efficient solution, but I just wanted to give you a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

React Native Async Storage don't have this feature